# In a mysql db, can you count the number of occurrences of a value in a column as an autogenerated column?

Tags: mysql

I have found many Q&As about counting the number of occurrences of a value in a column. However, they are all aimed at outputting data for the entire selection, whereas I want to auto-generate a column where the number of occurrences of a value up until that row is displayed.

Background to my problem is I have a db where each row is a match between 2 football teams with all kinds of stats. I want to auto-generate 2 columns which displays how many matches the hometeam and awayteam have played previous to this match, this season. So the first three columns below I already have but want to generate the last two, hometeam_previous_matches and awayteam_previous_matches.

```
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Id | Season | Hometeam       | Awayteam       | hometeam_previous_matches | awayteam_previous_matches |
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 |      1 | Bournemouth    | Aston Villa    |                           |                               |
|  2 |      1 | Chelsea        | Swansea        |                           |                               |
|  3 |      1 | Everton        | Watford        |                           |                               |
|  4 |      1 | Leicester      | Sunderland     |                           |                               |
|  5 |      1 | Man Utd        | Tottenham      |                           |                               |
|  6 |      1 | Norwich        | Crystal Palace |                           |                               |
|  7 |      1 | Arsenal        | West Ham       |                           |                               |
|  8 |      1 | Newcastle      | Southampton    |                           |                               |
|  9 |      1 | Stoke          | Liverpool      |                           |                               |
| 10 |      1 | West Brom      | Man City       |                           |                               |
| 11 |      1 | Aston Villa    | Man Utd        |                           |                               |
| 12 |      1 | Southampton    | Everton        |                           |                               |
| 13 |      1 | Sunderland     | Norwich        |                           |                               |
| 14 |      1 | Swansea        | Newcastle      |                           |                               |
| 15 |      1 | Tottenham      | Stoke          |                           |                               |
| 16 |      1 | Watford        | West Brom      |                           |                               |
| 17 |      1 | West Ham       | Leicester      |                           |                               |
| 18 |      1 | Crystal Palace | Arsenal        |                           |                               |
| 19 |      1 | Man City       | Chelsea        |                           |                               |
| 20 |      1 | Liverpool      | Bournemouth    |                           |                               |
| 21 |      1 | Crystal Palace | Aston Villa    |                           |                               |
| 22 |      1 | Leicester      | Tottenham      |                           |                               |
| 23 |      1 | Man Utd        | Newcastle      |                           |                               |
| 24 |      1 | Norwich        | Stoke          |                           |                               |
| 25 |      1 | Sunderland     | Swansea        |                           |                               |
| 26 |      1 | West Ham       | Bournemouth    |                           |                               |
| 27 |      1 | Everton        | Man City       |                           |                               |
| 28 |      1 | Watford        | Southampton    |                           |                               |
| 29 |      1 | West Brom      | Chelsea        |                           |                               |
| 30 |      1 | Arsenal        | Liverpool      |                           |                               |
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I can add more rows to question if necessary with another Season as well, but don't want the post to get too big.

I want the auto-generated columns to "reset" for each new season, i.e. when seasonnr changes. I can probably figure that out myself (more educative that way), if I just get help with the above example.

Comment: Why not simply calculate it on-the-fly?

Comment: Will look into it, thanks

Comment: @Strawberry I looked into it but haven't found good info. I'm new to mysql. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, I edited the question. I'm new to Stackoverflow as well btw. Just let me know if this isn't enough for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You should provide the code that you tried, and why it failed. SO is not about solving your problem, It is about helping you solve your own problem... 

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY? And "home_matches" means "how many previous matches has the home team played (regardless of whether those matches are home or away", right?

Comment: "how many matches .... have played previous to this match, this season" can only be calculated if the date for a match is know.

Comment: @Strawberry ID is my PK. Your second question, yes. Edited the Q to better reflect what I want.

Comment: @Luuk yes but I haven't really tried any code as I don't know where to start. I have searched a lot for an A to my Q but haven't found anything useful. If you know what technique to use or any keywords that could help me in the right direction I am all ears:) You say you need a date, does it work with ID? ID is in the order the matches were played. However, when the league changes the ID keeps ticking up from what it was on the last game of the previous league. The dates were messed up in the excelfile I imported from unfortunately. If it is absolutely necessary I can try parsing them somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,season INT NOT NULL 
,home_team VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL       
,away_team VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1,1,'Bournemouth','Aston Villa'),
( 2,1,'Chelsea','Swansea'),
( 3,1,'Everton','Watford'),
( 4,1,'Leicester','Sunderland'),
( 5,1,'Man Utd','Tottenham'),
( 6,1,'Norwich','Crystal Palace'),
( 7,1,'Arsenal','West Ham'),
( 8,1,'Newcastle','Southampton'),
( 9,1,'Stoke','Liverpool'),
(10,1,'West Brom','Man City'),
(11,1,'Aston Villa','Man Utd'),
(12,1,'Southampton','Everton'),
(13,1,'Sunderland','Norwich'),
(14,1,'Swansea','Newcastle'),
(15,1,'Tottenham','Stoke'),
(16,1,'Watford','West Brom'),
(17,1,'West Ham','Leicester'),
(18,1,'Crystal Palace','Arsenal'),
(19,1,'Man City','Chelsea'),
(20,1,'Liverpool','Bournemouth'),
(21,1,'Crystal Palace','Aston Villa'),
(22,1,'Leicester','Tottenham'),
(23,1,'Man Utd','Newcastle'),
(24,1,'Norwich','Stoke'),
(25,1,'Sunderland','Swansea'),
(26,1,'West Ham','Bournemouth'),
(27,1,'Everton','Man City'),
(28,1,'Watford','Southampton'),
(29,1,'West Brom','Chelsea'),
(30,1,'Arsenal','Liverpool');

SELECT x.*
     , MAX(CASE WHEN y.team = x.home_team THEN y.running END) home_matches
     , MAX(CASE WHEN y.team = x.away_team THEN y.running END) away_matches
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.*
            ,  COUNT(b.id) running
         FROM    
            ( SELECT id
                   , home_team team 
                FROM my_table
               UNION ALL
              SELECT id
                   , away_team 
                FROM my_table
            ) a
         LEFT
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT id
                     , home_team team 
                  FROM my_table
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT id
                     , away_team 
                  FROM my_table
            ) b
           ON b.team = a.team
          AND b.id < a.id
        GROUP
           BY a.id
            , a.team
      ) y
     ON y.id = x.id
  GROUP
     BY x.id;
     
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | season | home_team      | away_team      | home_matches | away_matches |
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |      1 | Bournemouth    | Aston Villa    |            0 |            0 |
|  2 |      1 | Chelsea        | Swansea        |            0 |            0 |
|  3 |      1 | Everton        | Watford        |            0 |            0 |
|  4 |      1 | Leicester      | Sunderland     |            0 |            0 |
|  5 |      1 | Man Utd        | Tottenham      |            0 |            0 |
|  6 |      1 | Norwich        | Crystal Palace |            0 |            0 |
|  7 |      1 | Arsenal        | West Ham       |            0 |            0 |
|  8 |      1 | Newcastle      | Southampton    |            0 |            0 |
|  9 |      1 | Stoke          | Liverpool      |            0 |            0 |
| 10 |      1 | West Brom      | Man City       |            0 |            0 |
| 11 |      1 | Aston Villa    | Man Utd        |            1 |            1 |
| 12 |      1 | Southampton    | Everton        |            1 |            1 |
| 13 |      1 | Sunderland     | Norwich        |            1 |            1 |
| 14 |      1 | Swansea        | Newcastle      |            1 |            1 |
| 15 |      1 | Tottenham      | Stoke          |            1 |            1 |
| 16 |      1 | Watford        | West Brom      |            1 |            1 |
| 17 |      1 | West Ham       | Leicester      |            1 |            1 |
| 18 |      1 | Crystal Palace | Arsenal        |            1 |            1 |
| 19 |      1 | Man City       | Chelsea        |            1 |            1 |
| 20 |      1 | Liverpool      | Bournemouth    |            1 |            1 |
| 21 |      1 | Crystal Palace | Aston Villa    |            2 |            2 |
| 22 |      1 | Leicester      | Tottenham      |            2 |            2 |
| 23 |      1 | Man Utd        | Newcastle      |            2 |            2 |
| 24 |      1 | Norwich        | Stoke          |            2 |            2 |
| 25 |      1 | Sunderland     | Swansea        |            2 |            2 |
| 26 |      1 | West Ham       | Bournemouth    |            2 |            2 |
| 27 |      1 | Everton        | Man City       |            2 |            2 |
| 28 |      1 | Watford        | Southampton    |            2 |            2 |
| 29 |      1 | West Brom      | Chelsea        |            2 |            2 |
| 30 |      1 | Arsenal        | Liverpool      |            2 |            2 |
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! This obviously gets the job done since in your answer, you create the table and then calculate the new columns as per what the question asked for. Thank you so much! I realize now I was a long way from making this happening on my own. Great example which I will definitely come back to for reference.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8+, then you can probably use LAG, or some-such to simplify this process. But this should work well-enough for modest data sets

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   m1.Id,
   m1.Season,
   m1.Hometeam,
   m1.Awayteam,
   (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM mytable m2 
    WHERE m2.Hometeam = m1.Hometeam
      AND m2.Id < m1.Id) hometeam_previous_matches,
   (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM mytable m3 
    WHERE m3.Awayteam = m1.Awayteam
      AND m3.Id < m1.Id)    awayteamteam_previous_matches 
FROM
   mytable m1
```

Above query is untested. You will have to change `mytable` to the table name that you are using.

The query assumes that the ordering on Id has the same order as ordering on match-date.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This answer had less code but only counts how many previous matches a team has played at home previously, or away previously. Not the total number of matches previously played. But maybe it can be changed to achieve that? I will look into it after I have read up on exactly what is happening in the query:) What throws me a bit is the m1. m2. and m3. What do they do? Thank you again.